# Fortify Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration with ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, fortify

I ran into fortify alert for the below code and the error is `Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration`

my controller class is below for exception handling

```
class MyController {
...
    @ExceptionHandler
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        public ErrorResponse handleRequestNotFoundException(RequestNotFoundException exception) {
            log.error("The request was not found", exception);
            return ErrorResponse.builder().message("Request not found").build();
        }
...
}
```

and the exception class is ,

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "No such request found")
public class RequestNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

Can somebody please help how we can get rid off this alert ? Thanks in advance